# Viewing a screencast encoded with camtasia

Tags: video

I have downloaded the screencast on this page,  http://jaderholm.com/screencasts/org-mode/.

I can watch in firefox but the viewer has limited controls. So I would rather watch it on   a regular video application. The thing is I've tried everything and I get sound in all and video in none. "mediainfo" says it is using the "Shockwave" codec. It is obvious the video was made with Camstudio. I seem to remember that Camstudio uses it's own proprietary codec for recording.

Is there an actual Shockwave codec? How can I view a video encoded with it on Linux?

How an I view a video using the Camtasia codec on Linux.

---

PS.
Technically I am not supposed to link directly to that video since the URL is subject to change. I am supposed to link to:
http://jaderholm.com/screencasts.html

Comment: Have you read about this yet http://techsmith.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/154/~/camtasia-studio%3A-avi-videos-created-in-camtasia-studio-do-not-play-on-other

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, VLC is full of codecs and can usually play most anything. If you have the direct link to the screencast, you can open it in VLC by going to File -> Open Network Stream (or similar) and pasting the link.

Comment: `mplayer` and `vlc` plays only audio...

Comment: @pbm not just mplayer, there's a thread telling many user on Windows sees only audio as well, you need to read the link in my comment

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the `file` command line utility to see which format the file is, then google for a program that can open it, or maybe post its output here to help us helping you.